# Mixed Content Warnings in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, plugins

I'm having some issues with mixed content warnings on the following page:

https://www.tdmgroup.net/get-touch/

The image that is causing the warnings seems to be

[image]
    (https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_greenA.png)

I think that it's Visual Composer that is loading the Gmaps API and so I checked for any references in the plugin folder, but I couldn't find anything.

Visual Composer states it had fixed the mixed content warnings in a previous version but the plugin I'm using is the latest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is not under visual composer control yo ushould check gmaps shortcode url protocol. inside edit form -> frame url -> it must be same as your site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37903102/3599237